# No puedo mostrar un formulario modal popup

Tags: jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc, css3

Trabajo con ASP.NET MVC 5 no puedo mostrar un formulario modal popup cuando lo llamo desde un botón flotante se muestra y automaticmente se cierra solo se ve segundos la vista modal popup. Muestro código.

HTML

```
<div class="contenedor">
            <button class="botonF1">
                <span>+</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn botonF2">
                <span>+</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn botonF3">
                <span>+</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn botonF4">
                <span>+</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn botonF5" onclick="llamarVistaParcial();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <span>+</span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

MODAL desde el Index

```
div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="modal-content" >
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h5 class="modal-title" >Proveedor</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
*{


 margin:0;

    }
header{
  height:170px;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:Sans-serif;
  background:#009688;
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-left:50px;
}
.contenedor{
  width:90px;
  height:240px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}
.botonF1{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:#F44336;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  margin-right:16px;
  margin-bottom:16px;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:36px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  transition:.3s;  
}
span{
  transition:.5s;  
}
.botonF1:hover span{
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}
.botonF1:active{
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
.btn{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:none;
  color:#FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  font-size:28px;
  outline:none;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin-right:26px;
  transform:scale(0);

    }
.botonF2{
  background:#2196F3;
  margin-bottom:85px;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.botonF3{
  background:#673AB7;
  margin-bottom:130px;
  transition:0.7s;
}
.botonF4{
  background:#009688;
  margin-bottom:175px;
  transition:0.9s;
}
.botonF5{
  background:#FF5722;
  margin-bottom:220px;
  transition:0.99s;
}
.animacionVer{
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.botonF1').hover(function () {
    $('.btn').addClass('animacionVer');
})
$('.contenedor').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.btn').removeClass('animacionVer');
})
});
```

JS POPUP

```
<script>
            function llamarVistaParcial() {
                var laURLDeLaVista = '@Url.Action("CreatePV", "Proveedor")';
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    type: "GET",
                    url: laURLDeLaVista,
                    data: {},
                    success: function (response) {
                        //$('#resultado').html('');
                        $('#resultado').html(response);
                    }
                });
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            };
        </script>
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿&times para que es?: `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>`

Comment: @A.Cedano es para cerrar el modal el `&times;` representa en HTML a `X`.

Comment: @PedroÁvila No veo ningún problema en tu código, intenta presionar las teclas `ctrl + F5` teniendo abierta el inspector de código del navegador esto refrescara la pagina y eliminara el cache

Comment: Hola Pedro, esta vez no me quedó clara tu pregunta, ¿el modal se muestra unos segundos y luego se cierra?

Comment: @Flxtr Así es amigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que deberías añadir el `$("#myModal").modal('show');` dentro del `success` de la llamada `ajax`.

Al ser una llamada asíncrona, el modal no se abre justo después de tener el html incrustado. Tendría que abrirse justo después de recibir el `response`. El resultado final sería así:

```
$.ajax({
   cache: false,
   async: true,
   type: "GET",
   url: laURLDeLaVista,
   data: {},
   success: function (response) {
       $('#resultado').html(response);
       $("#myModal").modal('show');
   }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Estoy seguro que es problema del orden en que has agregado los .css y .js, y puede que incluso no hayas agregado alguno de bootstrap. Para la otra aporta un Jsfiddle, o al menos indica si hay error en consola o no.

Mira este Jsfiddle que te hice:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/29nvq5rf/

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio. Te recomiendo colocar el código del jsfiddle aquí puesto que eso haría que tu respuesta sea más completa y auto sostenida. Cabe resaltar que los enlaces son para brindar información adicional y, en el peor de los casos, pueden expirar, por lo que si la respuesta depende solo de enlaces externos y ellos se quiebran, entonces la respuesta pierde su esencia. Adicional a esta edición, puedes mantener el enlace al jsfiddle.